# microsoft graph API - $filter with from email & $search

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I need a Microsoft graph API query to retrieve mails based on from email filter & contains a particular word.

There are ready API's to do these thing individually.

To retrieve mails based on from - email address:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq 'member_services@outlook.com'
```

To retrieve mails based on a search term

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search=get
```

But I need a query that does the both together.

I tried combining them with '&' but it's not working.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search=get&$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq'member_services@outlook.com'
```

This query is giving bad request error.

[image]

Please help me with a proper query that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing space after `eq` operator but it's not important because the query parameter `$filter` is not supported with `$search`.

You can use only `$search` and specify `from` and the term like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="from:member_services@outlook.com AND get"
```

Resources:

[Using $search on message collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-query-parameter?tabs=http#using-search-on-message-collections)